# Aurelias Bundling Process using TypeScript

Tags: bundle, aurelia

I'm using the asp.net 5 typescript skeleton. When I bundle the application, inside the "dist" folder, I'm seeing a bunch of html and js files. According to the bundles.js file as in:

```
"bundles": {
"dist/app-build": {
  "includes": [
    "[**/*.js]",
    "**/*.html!text",
    "**/*.css!text"
  ],
```

If I'm thinking correctly, I should the the bundled version of those file with an app-build.html and app-build.js, yes. Instead I see all the files basically within the "src" folder.

What is working correctly though is the aurelia.js file is being generated properly from the following:

```
 "dist/aurelia": {
  "includes": [
    "aurelia-framework",
    "aurelia-materialize-bridge",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper",
    "aurelia-fetch-client",
    more stuff here...
```

I haven't changed the skeleton at all. Just trying to get things to work.

Any ideas what may be going on?

Thank much

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely and I'm not using the asp.net version of the skeleton but my Aurelia Typescript app has the following bundle config:

```
"dist/app-build": {
  "includes": [
    "[*.js]",
    "*.html!text",
    "[*/**/*.js]",
    "*/**/*.html!text",
    "*/**/*.css!text"
  ]
```

In my case index.html, app.ts (view root) and main.ts (aurelia config) are located in the 'root' folder *src*. The rest of my code is located in subdirectories.

Comment: Just getting back to this. I'm using the lates build for .NET Core and things are working nicely. Thanks all.